# Nvidia Nsight Graphic makes memory crash

Tags: memory, graphics, vulkan, nsight

I am using Nsight Graphics 2023.2 to debug my Vulkan 1.3 program, which works well. But when I click the "VS" in API inspector to check my vertex shader stage information, I can see the Nsight Program is using more and more memory from Windows Task Manager, finally my computer went shutdown.
Since it is directly lead to a shutdown, I can't provide a crash report.
QAQ

I have tried to modify my shader and reduce the data transferred from CPU to GPU, but it seems like useless.

Comment: This isn't a question, and unlikely to be something SO can help with. I'd suggest raising it on the Nvidia developer forums.